# Exclude featured image and custom field from this get_attachment query

Tags: query, exclude

Is there a way I can exclude the post thumbnail AND a custom field with the value "`_lm_comm_logo`" from this query that pulls all of the images associated with a particular post?

```
<?php $args = array('numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_parent' => $post->ID); ?>
                <?php if ( $photos = get_posts($args) ) : ?>
                    <div class="slides">
                        <?php foreach ( $photos as $photo ) : ?>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <a href="<?php echo $photo->guid; ?>" class="lightbox" rel="community[<?php echo $post->ID; ?>]"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: are you storing the custom field as an actual attachment or just the URL as a text field?

Comment: Rather than editing your question to post the solution, please post your entire solution as an answer and mark it as "the" answer so that others can find it.

Answer (score 1):

The asker refused to post his solution as answer, so I took the liberty to get this question out of our growing *Unanswered Questions* list …

```
<?php 
$logo = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_lm_comm_logo', true);
$map  = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_lm_comm_map', true);

$args = array(
    'numberposts'    => -1, 
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order', 
    'order'          => 'ASC', 
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'exclude'        =>  array($logo,$map),
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID
); 

if ( $photos = get_posts($args) ) : ?>
    <div class="slides">
        <?php foreach ( $photos as $photo ) : ?>
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="<?php 
                    echo $photo->guid; 
                ?>" class="lightbox" rel="community[<?php 
                    echo $post->ID; 
                ?>]"><?php 
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID, 'thumbnail'); 
                ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php
endif;
```